# Domain of composite of function and its inverse

Tags: inverse-function

I'm looking for the domain of definition of the  composite function of one function and its inverse.

Let $$H(x)= \frac{e^x -1}{e^x +1} $$ and its inverse $$G(x)=\ln{ \frac{x+1}{1-x}}$$

Is $-1 <x <1 $ the domain of definition of $H(G(x))$ ?

What is weird is that by going through the computer algebra tool Mathematica, I get $\mathbb{R}$ as the domain.
I think the tool does a simplification and gets the identity function, and that explains why I get $\mathbb{R}$ as the domain.
Am I right?

The graph of $$ \frac{x+1}{1-x}: $$
[image]

The graph of $H(x)$ in blue and $G(x)$ in orange:
[image]

Comment: According to your domain you could I put x=0 but that would be log(-1). You're probably right though about the answer the computer gave.

Comment: A few comments: (1) When you post a question, it should read as a single, unified whole, not a post with several edits.  Anyone who is interested can see the edit history.  Please do not add comments into your question indicating where it has been edited.  (2) I understand that the original version of your question was not what you actually wanted to ask.  However, editing a question to completely change its meaning *after* it has been answered is generally considered poor form.  (3) What CAS are you using?  Different systems behave differently---knowing what you are using would help.

Comment: I made a mistake in writing the function, please look at the correct is $G(X)$, there is not issue with ln when x=0

Comment: what do you mean by CAS please ? Mathematica

Comment: A CAS is a "computer algebra system."

Comment: I *think* that your comment regarding the mistake in the formula was directed at @Anon .  However, you did not "@-ping' that user, so it is likely that they won't see your comment (that being said, I just @-pinged them for you).

Comment: Thanks for the formatting and for the tips @XanderHenderson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those places in mathematics where the language gets a little muddy, and where authors often use words differently.  From reading your question I can *infer* some things, but it would not be unreasonable to consult the source from which you are working.

Usually, we require three data when defining a function:  (1) a domain, (2) a codomain, and (3) a (unique) pairing of each element in a the domain to some element of the codomain.  However, as a practical matter, we often elide the an explicit statement of the domain and/or codomain, and take the domain to be the largest set in our "universe" for which the formula makes sense.  This gives us a *domain of definition*.

In this case, it appears that you are working over $\mathbb{R}$.  Thus both $G$ and $H$ are functions which act on subsets of the real numbers.  The function $H$ is defined by the formula
$$ H(x) = \frac{\mathrm{e}^x-1}{\mathrm{e}^x + 1}. $$
This formula gives a well-defined real number for any real number $x$, and so we say that the domain of definition for $H$ is $\mathbb{R}$.

The function $G$ is defined by the formula
$$ G(x) = \ln\left( \frac{x+1}{1-x} \right). $$
This function *does not* give a well-defined real number for all real numbers $x$.  Indeed, if $(x+1)/(x-1) \le 0$, then the logarithm is undefined.  Thus the domain of definition for $G$ cannot contain any values of $x$ for which this fraction is nonpositive.  Some quick algebra shows that
$$ \frac{x+1}{x-1} > 0 \iff x \in (-1, 1). $$
For any such $x$, the formula defining $G$ gives a well-defined real number, and so the domain of definition for $G$ is $(-1,1)$.

Finally, given two function $f$ and $g$ defined by formulae, the domain of definition of the composition $f\circ g$ consists of all of the points in the domain of definition of $g$, minus those points that are not mapped into the domain of definition of $f$.  That is,
$$ D(f\circ g) = D(g) \setminus \{ x\in D(f) \mid g(x) \not\in D(f) \}. $$
For the given functions $G$ and $H$,
$$ D(H\circ G) = D(G) \setminus \underbrace{\{ x\in D(G) \mid G(x) \not\in D(H) \}}_{\text{$=\varnothing$, see below}} = (-1,1)\setminus \varnothing = (-1,1).$$
The indicated term is the empty set, as there are no real values of $x$ (in the domain of $G$ or otherwise) which are not in the domain of $H$.

In other words, $H\circ G$ is only defined on the interval $(-1,1)$, and so this interval is the domain of definition of $H\circ G$.  On this interval, it is the identity function, i.e. $(H\circ G)(x) = x$.

Observe that if we define a function $F$ by $F(x) = x$, then *this* function has $\mathbb{R}$ as its domain of definition, because the defining formula is well-defined for all real inputs.  However, $F$ and $H\circ G$ are *not* the same function:  $F$ is defined by a formula with its domain understood implicitly, while $H\circ G$ is defined by the composition of two functions with previously understood domains of definition.  If you are using a computer algebra system (CAS) to compute the domain of the composition, it is very likely that the CAS is first simplifying the resulting formula for the composition, and then determining the domain.  This highlights how careful you need to be when working with computers.

Comment: I thank you for this greate explanation, it matches what I thought at the beginning. But tell me, the domain is] -1.1 [and not (-1.1) or simply (-1,1) it's another notation for ]-1,1[?

Comment: $]-1,1[$ and $(-1,1)$ are different notation for  the same set: $\{ x \in \mathbb{R} : -1 < x < 1\}$.  The notation $(-1,1)$ is the standard in the US (where I live).  I believe that $]-1,1[$ is a Bourbaki-style notation, and that it might, therefore, be more common in France?

Comment: You are absolutely right about Bourbaki and France, thanks again:). @Xander Henderson

Answer (score 1):

$G(x)$ is defined for $\frac{x+1}{x-1} \gt 0$, i.e. for  $x \in (-\infty, -1) \cup (1,\infty)$. Which is also the domain of $H \circ G$.

So you made a mistake in $H$ domain and the software you used too.

Comment: I dont see why the domain of G(x) is not -1<x<1 ?

Comment: You need to have $\frac{x+1}{x-1} \gt 0$, i.e $x+1, x-1$ to have the same sign.

Comment: we need x+1> 0 and x-1   =>  -1<x<1; and  x+1<0 and x-1>0 => not possible

Comment: For exemple for x=1/2 I have  ln(3) and for x=4 I have complexe number (the same hole for x in your domain)

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re doing... The ratio of two real numbers is positive when the two numbers are either both positive or either both negative. Just apply that to $x-1$ and $x+1$.

Comment: For $x=1/2$ you have $\frac{x+1}{x-1}= \frac{3/2}{-1/2}=-3$!!!

Comment: Please look at the graph of $(x+1)/(x-1)$, it's only positife of x in ]-1,1[. I also added the graph of $H(x)$ and $G(x)$ showing thant the G function is only defined on ]-1,1[. What'is wrong with this ??

Comment: Please i have miselad the G, so the correct G is   $$G(x)=\ln{ \frac{x+1}{1-x}}$$.